# OrderBy lambda fica mudando a cada pesquisa

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda, grid

Possuo uma pesquisa em lambda, em que se refere informações de uma grid, mas a cada consulta diferente ele muda as informações de lugar:

```
Indicadores = (Pegatodos().Where(f => f.STATUS == "A")
                       .Select(x => new 
           { SEQINDICFINANC = x.SEQ, DESCRICAO = x.DESCRICAO, SIGLA = x.SIGLA })
                         .OrderBy( x => x.SEQ)
                         .ToList())
```

ele retorna a informação principal do meu grid:

```
NOME  datas    |   datas |  datas
seq    0           0         0
seq    0           0         0
seq    0           0         0
seq    0           0         0
```

mas a cada consulta de períodos de datas diferentes a posição dos `seq` fica mudando, e eu preciso que fiquem sempre na mesma posição.

Comment: Verifique o tipo do seu atributo SEQ.

Comment: type virtual long no C# e number no BD

Comment: Você pode por favor colocar na sua pergunta o código de `Pegatodos()`?

Comment: estou usando o entity framework,no caso é o return padrão

return enditades

não sei exatamente o código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A alteração estava ocorrendo no script mesmo a mesma ordenação feita no C# eu usei no JS e funcionou, Obrigado

```
success: function (result) {
              var dataArray = [];
              var valarray = [];
              var datas = {}; 
              var total = 0;

              for (var j = 0, length = result.Datas.length; j < length; j++) {
                  var indicador = {};

                  for (var l = 0; l < result.Indicadores.length; l++) {
                      if (result.Datas[j].PKINDIC== result.Indicadores[l].PKINDIC) {
                          indicador.pkindic= result.Datas[j].PKINDIC;
                          indicador.descricao = result.Indicadores[l].DESCRICAO;
                          indicador.valor= result.Datas[j].VALOR;
                          indicador.dtas = result.Datas[j].DTA;
                          indicador.pkvari= result.Datas[j].PKVARI;

                          dataArray.push(indicador);
                      }
                  }
              }

              //#region BubbleSort DataArray

              for (var cont = 0; cont < dataArray.length; cont++) {
                  for (var cont2 = 0; cont2 < dataArray.length - 1; cont2++) {
                      if (dataArray[cont2].dtas > dataArray[cont2 + 1].dtas) {
                          var temp = dataArray[cont2 + 1];
                          dataArray[cont2 + 1] = dataArray[cont2];
                          dataArray[cont2] = temp;
                      }
                  }
              }

              //#endregion
```

Depois de pegar todos os resultados em 2 arrays diferentes e passar para um único com as informações que eu precisava, eu usei um método bubblesort para ordenar sendo assim, o que não tinha antes e na transformação de 2 arrays para 1 estava reordenando as informações de forma randômica e com esse método após a transformação criou uma ordenação fixa.

Gente obrigado pela ajuda, se alguém tiver algum problema parecido posta aqui

Answer (score 1):

Apenas inverta o `OrderBy` com o `Select`. O retorno de `Select` não garante uma lista ordenada:

```
Indicadores = (Pegatodos().Where(f => f.STATUS == "A")
              .OrderBy(x => x.SEQ)
              .Select(x => new { 
                  SEQINDICFINANC = x.SEQ, 
                  DESCRICAO = x.DESCRICAO, 
                  SIGLA = x.SIGLA })
              .ToList())
```

Comment: Continua trocando, a cada pesquisa  =/

Indicadores = (Pegatodos().OrderBy(x => x.SEQ)
                             .Where(f => f.STATUS == "A")
                             .Select(x => new { SEQINDICFINANC = x.SEQ, DESCRICAO = x.DESCRICAO, SIGLA = x.SIGLA })
                             .ToList())

Comment: Só pra eu entender: de onde vêm essas datas?

Comment: as datas, vem de parâmetro do método que é chamado de uma view e invocado por ajax, no caso o usuário que escolhe o período, expliquei certo?

Comment: É que não vejo correlação com o que está sendo executado. Por isso minha dúvida. Pode ser outro fator que está trocando os registros de ordem.

Comment: bom, a informação retorna para um script que usa Indicadores como base, e relaciona outras informações para gerar as linhas sem reorganizar ou alterar a Indicadores, apenas buscar informações usando ela como base, o estranho é que esse 'bug' só ocorre quando há mais de 3 registros, vou debugar aqui, e se encontrar uma resposta eu posto, Obrigado

Comment: está alterando realmente no script , porém no c# ele não está ordenando, os valores do seq estão embaralhados vou tentar ordenar pelo JS